# Correlating two distributions to a third

Tags: distributions, correlation, predictive-models

My dataset consists of 4-million records, each a combination of age, race, and a discrete observed value. The goal is to find a correlation between the combination of age/race and the observation, so that given a distribution of ages and races, a distribution of expected observations can be calculated.

I am looking into covariance matrices, but I  am unsure how to handle the categorical data in race. What is the correct direction to begin investigating?

```
Age     Race     X
24      Black    32
26      White    37
       ...
```

edit for newcomers: once I have obtained a linear model, I need to use distributions as inputs to receive a distribution as an output. I will not be predicting X for a single individual, but rather I need to determine the distribution of X for a given distribution of age/race. are there methods of transforming a linear model into something that can accomplish this?

edit again: in the simplest terms... give the data that I have (Age, Race, Observed X) I need to come up with a model whose inputs are a distribution of ages and a distribution of races (i.e. not a single age/race combination) and whose output is the expected distribution of X. I have already formed a linear model using R that can give me the expected X given a single value of Age and Race, but the model needs to work on population-level inputs/outputs, not individual-level.

Answer (score 1):

To get the probability distribution of X for each combination, normally I would suggest a Monte Carlo simulation using the results from your regression. Your software may have an inbuilt function to do the simulation.

However, you have 4 million records, which is a huge number. Do you know what percentage of the population (and subpopulations) you have? I'm wondering how many replicates you would need to simulate.

Comment: Because the predictions are linear, Monte Carlo is scarcely necessary: the exact calculations are fast and easy.  The interesting aspect of this question concerns how to provide prediction intervals for a *distribution.*

Comment: @whuber Right, eventually the calculations will be done in excel resulting in the probability distribution of discrete values of X, and when I change the age/race the X distribution would need to update quickly, so Monte Carlo would be out unless I wanted to pre-calculate X for each combination of age and race (~200 combinations) and take weighted averages of them on the fly.

Comment: So would it be resampling then?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use dummy variables (0/1 values) to identify each race, for each observation. For instance the first sample line would be extended to:

```
Age     White   Black   Asian
24      0       1       0
```

You can use these dummy variables in a linear regression study. Their coefficients can be interpreted as the slope adjustment of each race.

Comment: How do I use distributions as inputs to the linear model? When I get around to calculating, I won't have a single age or race, I'll have age: 25 +- 4, 80% white, 10% black, 8% hispanic, 2% other (for example)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are asking, but after you've fit the model you can enter all the observations for only the subset you're interested in (one specific race or age group) and plot your predictions, outcomes and residuals.

Comment: I made a second edit to the main post. The linear model I already have in R predicts individual-level X for an individual's age and race. I need this to operate at a population level, i.e. I will now that a% of the population is 10-20, b% is 20-30, etc. I will also know that x% of the population is white, y% is black, and so on. I need to determine the probability distribution of X for the combination of age/race distributions.